# Consulta de intervalo de fecha en Meses

Tags: sql-server

soy principiante en SQL server y estaba intendando una consulta en donde quiero obtener el rango de fecha de unos productos de hace 6 meses para adelante, he estado buscando pero ponen fechas estáticas he intentado con la clausula Between, por ejemplo:

```
Select * FROM [@PRODUCTOS] WHERE FECHALIBERACION = '2020/07/04'     
AND MONTH(FECHALIBERACION ) = '4';
```

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo hago uso de este intervalo?, o alguna sugerencia de que usar.

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener una fecha N cantidad de tiempo en el pasado puedes usar la función `DATEADD()` y pasarle un número negativo:

```
declare @fechaPasada date = DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())


Select * FROM [@PRODUCTOS] WHERE FECHALIBERACION >= @fechaPasada
```

`DATEADD()` toma como parámetro el intervalo de tiempo (dia, mes, año), la cantidad, y la fecha a modificar. En este caso el intervalo es meses (MONTH). Como son 6 meses hacia atrás entonces -6, y la fecha se obtiene con `GETDATE()` una función que te devuelve la fecha actual.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho, no sabia nada de la clausula DATEADD()