# Calcular fecha de vencimiento sql server, comparar fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta `sql`, y quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo una columna en una tabla, tipo datetime, en la cual almaceno una `fecha_inicio` ejemplo: "*6-18-2021*".

Ahora quiero compararla con la fecha actual. Mi intención es que cuando la fecha inicial haya trascurrido un mes exacto, se muestre en la consulta claramente comparándola con la actual.

**Ejemplo**: `Fecha_inicial` "*6-18-2021*" la comparo con fecha actual "*7-18-2021*", en teoría esta fecha se debería de mostrar, ya que transcurrió un mes.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from cliente where fecha_inicial <= GETDATE();
```

Aquí me muestra todos los resultados. Pensaba en sumarle un mes a la fecha inicial para así compararla con la fecha actual, pero no se como hacerlo o si exista otra forma a lo que pretendo hacer.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Consulta de intervalo de fecha en Meses](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344569/consulta-de-intervalo-de-fecha-en-meses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente para sacar la diferencia de días se usa el DATEIFF.

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), Fecha_inicial )
FROM tuTabla WHERE DAY => 30

teniendo en cuenta que un mes puede tener 29 a 31 días, creo que te puede ser de ayuda

Comment: Gracias, fue de gran ayuda dicha respuesta para lo que pretendía hacer.